# Parse string and return only the information between bracket symbols. C# Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

I would like to parse a string to return only a value that is in between bracket symbols, such as `[10.2%]`.  Then I would need to strip the `"%"` symbol and convert the decimal to a rounded up/down integer.  So, `[10.2%]` would end up being `10`.  And, `[11.8%]` would end up being 12.

Hopefully I have provided sufficient information.

Comment: Sure, sufficient information for someone to do this _for_ you, but we don't operate that way. Please post your current code, showing use [what you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com) and explain what is not working and where you are stuck.

Answer (score 2):

```
Math.Round(
    double.Parse(
       "[11.8%]".Split(new [] {"[", "]", "%"}, 
       StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[0]))
```

Comment: how would I need to modify this to parse the string no matter what percentage is inside the brackets?

Comment: @MattMcHone - I don't follow. Examples are? What are different kinds of `%`?

Comment: range is anywhere from [0.1%] up to [100%].

Comment: @MattMcHone - OK. No changes required. Guess you do not understand what I posted or how it works.

Comment: @MattMcHone Instead of `"[11.8%]"` put your string variable.

Comment: @Oded, OK I understand now.. What if I cannot guarantee that the information between the brackets will be my percentage..  What if there is a string between the first brackets, such as [info]?  How can I ignore other brackets that don't contain my specific string?

Comment: @Rotem, thank you I figured that out after Oded said no changes were required.

Comment: @MattMcHone - Well, whatever way you go about it, you need to provide data in a consistent way. Instead of doing it all in one line, you can do this in several lines and use `double.TryParse` to see if the value within the `[]` is indeed a double (by the way - `100` will fail, as `double` expects a decimal point).

Comment: `Decimal.TryParse` might be a better fit here.

Comment: @Oded `double` can parse integers, the decimal point is optional.

Comment: @Rotem - I must be thinking about something else then.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use Regex?

In this example, I am assuming that your value inside the brackets always are a double with decimals.

```
string WithBrackets = "[11.8%]";
string AsDouble = Regex.Match(WithBrackets, "\d{1,9}\.\d{1,9}").value;
int Out = Math.Round(Convert.ToDouble(AsDouble.replace(".", ","));
```

Comment: Regex when `string.Split` will do?

Comment: @dotTutorials, how would I ignore brackets that contain other information, such as [info]?

Answer (score 0):

Use regular expressions (Regex) to find the required words within one bracket.
This is the code you need:
Use an foreach loop to remove the % and convert to int.

```
List<int> myValues = new List<int>();
foreach(string s in Regex.Match(MYTEXT, @"\[(?<tag>[^\]]*)\]")){
   s = s.TrimEnd('%');
   myValues.Add(Math.Round(Convert.ToDouble(s)));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var s = "[10.2%]";
var numberString = s.Split(new char[] {'[',']','%'},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).First();
var number = Math.Round(Covnert.ToDouble(numberString));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can ensure that the content between the brackets is of the form <decimal>%, then this little function will return the value between the fist set of brackets. If there are more than one values you need to extract then you will need to modify it somewhat.

```
public decimal getProp(string str)
{
    int obIndex = str.IndexOf("["); // get the index of the open bracket
    int cbIndex = str.IndexOf("]"); // get the index of the close bracket
    decimal d = decimal.Parse(str.Substring(obIndex + 1, cbIndex - obIndex - 2)); // this extracts the numerical part and converts it to a decimal (assumes a % before the ])
    return Math.Round(d); // return the number rounded to the nearest integer
}
```

For example `getProp("I like cookies [66.7%]")` gives the [`Decimal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.aspx) number 67